# How to set field2 = weekday +1

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm looking for code that will automatically enter in the next weekday's date into Field2 when Field1 is not null. Or more precisely Field2 = Field1 + 1 weekday

I am using Access 2007 as a front End and SQL 2008 as a backend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will be running a query from within Access against a linked SQL Server table, the query must use Access-compatible SQL.

To make `Field2` one day later than the `Field1` date:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Field2 = DateAdd('d', 1, Field1)
WHERE Field1 Is Not Null;
```

To skip over weekend days, use the `Weekday` function in a `Switch` statement to determine how many days to add.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Field2 =
    DateAdd
        (
            'd',
            Switch
                (
                    Weekday(Field1) = 6, 3,
                    Weekday(Field1) = 7, 2,
                    Weekday(Field1) >= 1 AND Weekday(Field1)<=5, 1
                ),
            Field1
        )
WHERE Field1 Is Not Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an `UPDATE` statement with `DATEADD`:

```
update YourTable 
set Field2 = dateadd(day,1,Field1)
where Field1 is not null
```

Or if you are trying to remove weekends and always update to the nearest Monday, then this is one way with `CASE`:

```
update YourTable 
set Field2 = 
  case 
    when datepart(dw,Field1) = 1 then dateadd(day,1,Field1)
    when datepart(dw,Field1) = 7 then dateadd(day,2,Field1)
    else dateadd(day,1,Field1)
  end
where Field1 is not null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d27f8/1)